# Webpack errors when resolving CSS urls

Tags: php, css, laravel, webpack

When I use a URL in a scss file and use that file (with @import) in a Vue component, I receive the following error:

Error: Cannot find module "../images/icons/home_grey.svg"

(that path is the path relative to my scss source file). How can I stop receiving that error? My webpack.mix.js file currently includes the following lines:

mix.setResourceRoot('/root/'); mix.copyDirectory('resources/assets/images', 'public/images');

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because if you are using css-loader, you need to give query param 'modules' as true. This will allow the loader to load modules.

something like this, for css-loader options,

```
                    options: {
                        modules: true,
                       }
```